# type related_site not listed in 'by type' tab list

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, documentation, related

The type "related_site" is not listed in the ['by type' tab](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=type#docs) in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to [related_site](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/related-site) has been added.